# Widget to show alarm information on HTC Desire

Tags: htc-desire, app-widgets, alarm

Is it possible to have information about scheduled alarms always visible on the screen? Ideally, as a widget with the list of alarms, or at least just the time of the next alarm somewhere, so I could always know this information at a glance, without opening alarm settings screen.

For now, I have to regularly check my alarm settings by clicking on the clock widget, which is inconvenient. Also, there is an alarm icon in the status bar, which is rather useless because I have several alarms at different times and at least one is always enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a widget called "Digital Clock Widget", free from the Market. It's a simple clock/date widget, which can be configured to also show the day and time of the next alarm.

Comment: There were many apps with the same name, but I found what I needed, thanks. In case somebody else will be interested, here is the link: http://www.appbrain.com/app/red.extension.DigitalClockWidget

Comment: Sorry for not being more exact, but yes, that's the one I meant :)

Answer (score 1):

[Alarm Master](http://www.appbrain.com/app/alarm-master/com.connectivetools.alarmmaster2) has a widget that shows the next alarm, but i think you need to set alarms from within that app, not the default alarm / clock app.

There's also [Upcomings](http://www.appbrain.com/app/upcomings-%28ads%29/com.allupcoming.events), which has a similar widget for showing the next event.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the next calendar event the Desire (and all HTC I think) don't need a 3rd party app. The HTC calendar widget which comes with the phone has 3 different view modes, the third does exactly that.

Unfortunately it works only with calendar events and not alarms...